# PHP Softlayer Object Storage Upload SSL error

Tags: php, ssl, upload, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

Thought I would drop a question, as this is giving me a proper headache

I have a PHP application which uploads files into SoftLayer Object Storage containers. 
To communicate with the Object Storage API I am using the PHP bindings from
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-php
and referenced them from my composer.json file

```
    "softlayer/objectstorage": "dev-master",
```

Retrieving object container files and urls is working all fine. 
But I keep having problems with uploading files though, specially depending on their size. It used to work couple of days ago but some reason stopped working recently

Here is the 'out-of-the-box' code I am using for uploading files:

```
$options = array('adapter' => ObjectStorage_Http_Client::SOCKET, 'timeout' => 10);
$objStorage = new ObjectStorage('', '', '', $options);

try {
   $newFile = $objStorage->with('RemoteFilePath')
                   ->setLocalFile($PathTolocalFile)
                   ->create();

   return $newFile->getUrl();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   return $e->getMessage();
}
```

For some reason, uploading a file that is under 1Mb works. But any file with a size bigger than this, the ->create() request eventually times out, no exception is thrown and I keep getting these error in my log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - [05/06/16 03:47:02] Warning: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry (/var/www/vendor/softlayer/objectstorage/lib/ObjectStorage/Http/Adapter/Socket.php:132)
```

As those bindings are essentially a wrapper round curl, I then tested with CURL myself see if I could upload a file bigger than 1M to Softlayer Storage Container. It turns out it succeeded using CURL both on my dev machine and staging server!

```
curl -i -XPUT -H "X-Auth-Token: {{MyAuthToken}}" --data-binary "@BigFile.txt" https://lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/{{MyAuthTokenKey}}/{{MyContainer}}/BigFile.txt
```

Have you ever come across this? I don't understand why it suddenly stopped working.
Has anyone any idea?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your issue, I was able to upload files higher than 2 MB using your code. 
Anyway, the issue that you have is related to SSL/OpenSSL broken, take a look the following links in order to get more information about it and how to solve it:

- [Bug #54439  SSL/OpenSSL
  broken](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54439&edit=3)
- [fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
  messages:\nerror:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write
  retry IN
  PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350550/fwrite-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messages-nerror1409f)
- [Why am I getting “error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:
  bad write retry” error while attempting an
  SSL_write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997218/why-am-i-getting-error1409f07fssl-routinesssl3-write-pending-bad-write-retr)